# Estimation of the Kolmogorov test power [Rstudio].

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, simulation

Let $x$ be a 20-element sample from the T-Student distribution with 4 degree of freedom. I want to do a simulation to estimate the power of the Kolmogorov test for $H_0=F\sim N(0,1)$ if $\alpha=0.01$.

My idea:

```
n=1000 #number of simulations
alpha=0.1
m=c()
for (i in 1:n){
  x=rt(20,4)
  pV=ks.test(x=x,y="pnorm")$p.value
  m[i]=pV
}
power=m[m<alpha]
print(mean(power))#result
```

Is this way correct?

Answer (score 2):

I can't help you with the particular programming implementation, but the statistical implementation is simple.

1. Generate a random sample of $n = 20$ from a Student $t$ distribution with $\nu = 4$ degrees of freedom.
2. Compute the KS test statistic on this sample and the resulting $p$-value.
3. Count the number of $p$-values that are less than $\alpha$.

The power of the test is then the number of correct rejections of the null divided by the number of simulations; i.e., the number obtained in Step 3 above divided by the total number of samples generated.

My implementation in *Mathematica* is one line:

```
Length[Select[ParallelTable[KolmogorovSmirnovTest[
    RandomVariate[StudentTDistribution[4], 20]], {10^3}], # < 0.01 &]]/10.^3
```

This is for $10^3$ simulations of a $t$-distribution with $\nu = 4$ degrees of freedom and $n = 20$ realizations per sample and $\alpha = 0.01$.  The resulting power is small, only about $6.6\%$.  Among $10^6$ simulations, the power was about $0.06564$.  This suggests that the Student $t$ distribution with $\nu = 4$ is difficult for the KS test to distinguish from a normal distribution at a sample size of $n = 20$.

If you increase the sample size, you would expect the power to increase.  At $n = 200$, with all else the same, the power increases to about $54.7\%$.  At $\alpha = 0.05$, we have a power of about $74.5\%$.

Comment: You correctly state in (3) that we need to count the number of rejections. (+) From which one can get the reqyured proportion. You used $\alpha = 0.01$ instead of $\alpha = 0.1,$ as did I on my first try.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track until the very end. What
you call `power` isn't really power.

You are isolating the P-values that are smaller than
$\alpha = 0.1$ and then averaging them. That's not
exactly what you want.

You want the probability of
rejection. That is the probability that the P-value
is less than or equal to $0.1.$

Here is my suggested code:

```
set.seed(602)
m = 10^5;  n = 20
pv = replicate(m, ks.test(rt(n, 4), "pnorm")$p.val )
mean(pv <= .1)
[1] 0.12209
2*sd(pv <= .01)/sqrt(m)
[1] 0.0007422931 # aprx 95% margin of sim err
```

So the P-value is about $0.1221 \pm 0.0007.$

The vector `pv <= .1` is a logical vector of `TRUE`s
and `FALSE`s. Its `mean` is its proportion of `TRUE`s.

---

To show that your code doesn't give correct answers
I made the data standard normal, so the rejection rate
should be $0.1.$  But I get about $0.05$ instead.

```
n=1000 #number of simulations
alpha=0.1
m=c()
for (i in 1:n){
 x=rnorm(20)
 pV=ks.test(x=x,y="pnorm")$p.value
 m[i]=pV
}
power=m[m<alpha]
print(mean(power))#result
[1] 0.05010002
```